# I need help to draw a Polygon

Tags: java

I am trying to draw a certain type of polygon but i can't manage to get it to work. Are my formula wrong ? And if so, can you help me?

I want to draw a polygon using Java.awt.polygon

```java
TMP = new Polygon();

// this.getX() and this.getY() return an int
// consider getX() and getY() as x0 and y0

int x1,x2,x3,x4;
int y1,y2,y3,y4;

x1 = (int)  Math.round(this.getX() - this.getLength() * Math.cos(this.getAngle()));
y1 = (int)  Math.round(this.getY() - this.getLength() * Math.sin(this.getAngle()));

x3 = (int)  Math.round(x1 - this.getWidth() * Math.cos((Math.PI / 2) - this.getAngle()));
y3 = (int)  Math.round(y1 + this.getWidth() * Math.sin((Math.PI/2) - this.getAngle()));

x4 = (int)  Math.round(this.getX() - this.getWidth() * Math.cos((Math.PI/2) - this.getAngle()));
y4 = (int)  Math.round(this.getX() + this.getWidth() * Math.sin((Math.PI/2) - this.getAngle()));

x2 = (int)  Math.round((x1 + x3) / 2 + Math.cos(this.getAngle()) * this.getLength() / 2);
y2 = (int)  Math.round((y1 + y3) / 2 + Math.sin(this.getAngle()) * this.getLength() / 2);

TMP.addPoint(this.getX(), this.getY());
TMP.addPoint(x1, y1);
TMP.addPoint(x2, y2);
TMP.addPoint(x3, y3);
TMP.addPoint(x4, y4);
this.setPolygon(TMP);
```

This is what i expect 
https://i.gyazo.com/bdd8510d0128bab6347bb6c110f03c92.png

And i'm getting this
https://i.gyazo.com/55a00ae07d4f31732db12805fa592aec.png

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at your formulas, but by far the most confusing thing about getting started with manually drawing things is that with awt/Swing, the coordination system is different from what you have in maths: its origin is at the top left (rather than bottom left), and higher y values mean "down" (rather than "up").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My formulas were right. My values for length and widths were incorrect. My width was my length and mylength was my width. Sorry!